# Navigation.PushAsync doesn't seem to be showing next page although hitting the constructor

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating a multi-page Xamarin application that allows the user to login in and view locations against that user.

I am able to show the login screen, the user can login via calls to a local database however when I try and use `Navigation.PushAsync` to go to the next page, although hitting the constructor for the next page, nothing seems to happen.

I believe it may have something to do with this section of code here.

*Login.xaml.cs*

```
    public Login()
    {
        _Login login = new _Login();
        this.BindingContext = login;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

I've set the `Login` page as my Main page in `App.xaml.cs` however in the constructor I set the binding context to a class called _login. This class gets and sets the email and password for the user when they login and calls off to an external solution to access the sql database. (This all works correctly).

On the `login` button such as this:

*Login.xaml*

```
        <Button Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"
                Text="Login"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                FontSize="Large"></Button>
```

Which when clicked calls off to the `SubmitCommand` function as seen below:

*_login.cs*

```
    public async void OnSubmit()
    {
        SignInResponse response = await _clientBl.SignInAsync(Email, Password);

        Login login = new Login();

        if(response.WasSuccessful == true)
        {
            login.LoginSuccessful(response.User);
        }
        else
        {
            // Show error alert
        }
    }
```

Which, if successful, calls a function in *Login.xaml.cs*

```
    public async void LoginSuccessful(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        // Go to home page
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage
        {
            BindingContext = user
        });
    }
```

which simply pushes a new page and sets the binding context to that of the user. The code hits the constructor in *MainPage.xaml.cs* however the page is never loaded up. The MainPage contains a stacklayout with a list view

```
<StackLayout>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}"
              ItemSelected="Locations_ItemSelected"
              x:Name="listView">
        <ListView.RowHeight>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Int32">
                <On Platform="iOS">100</On>
                <On Platform="Android">100</On>
            </OnPlatform>
        </ListView.RowHeight>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}"
                                Aspect="AspectFill" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></Image>
                        <Label Margin="5" 
                                Text="{Binding Name}"
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                TextColor="White"
                                FontSize="25"></Label>
                        <Label Text="{Binding LocationID}"
                               IsVisible="False"></Label>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

which is populated through overriding the `OnAppear()` function. Could the issue be that I am sending this page an `ApplicationUser` and it is trying to bind the properties in that page to that class?

I did try and replacing the `Navigation.PushAsync` with `await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());` however it still doesn't show the next page.

Comment: why does OnSubmit create a new instance of Login?  Is that your Login.xaml page, or a different helper class?

Comment: @Jason I needed to access the `LoginSuccessful` method so that I could navigate from to the next page as from my understanding, you cannot use `Navigation` in a class. Or is that incorrect? No, the could in which this lies is a class called `_logn` which is referenced from the `login.xaml.cs` as seen in the code above. When the user clicks the login button, it hits the SubmitCommand which does the log in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you are creating a NEW instance of the Login page.  You want to use the EXISITNG instance that is already being displayed to the user

```
Login login = new Login();

if(response.WasSuccessful == true)
{
  login.LoginSuccessful(response.User);
```

there are a lot of different ways to approach this, but the simplest is probably

```
var login = (Login)Application.Current.MainPage;

if(response.WasSuccessful == true)
{
  login.LoginSuccessful(response.User);
```

or if your `MainPage` is a `NavigationPage`

```
var nav = (NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage;
var login = (Login)nav.CurrentPage;
```

Comment: Hi Jason, I am getting an error on this line `(Login)Application.Current.MainPage;` stating that the specified cast was invalid

Comment: is Login wrapped in a NavigationPage?  If so, then you should cast to NavigationPage and then get Login from that.

Comment: Yes, in the `App.xaml.cs` I have the following `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Login());`

Comment: Yeah. That seems to have been it

Answer (score 0):

Most likely from the behavior you are describing (and looking at your code), it sounds like it's because the PushAsync is not being run on the UI thread, and this causes the app to load the page on a separate thread. So your app is probably, it's just launching the page on a different thread.

Try to change it to the following:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage
    {
        BindingContext = user
    });
});
```

Let me know if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

For my case this happened because I accidentally had pushed the Login page as Modal on the navigation stack. On that (modal) Login Page I had a "register" button which triggered an pushAsync on the Navigation Stack. The Page "didn't show" although i saw its on the navigation stack in debug because the modal was still above it.

The Solution in that case was to simply not push the Login Page as Modal on the Navigation stack.